# Using mailx in a bash script running under systemd

Tags: bash, systemd, mailx

I am trying to get a bash script that sends email with attachment to be executed by systemd.  Running the script from the command line works fine, but when systemd runs it, the mailx command does not send the email.

```
# email report
/usr/bin/mailx -a $OUTFILE -s "SYSTEM REPORT `date '+%A, %B %d, %Y'`" \
   "mygmailaddress@gmail.com"  << EOF
System report attached
EOF
```

My .service file contains this:

```
[Service]
User=myuser
Group=mygroup
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/home/myuser/bin/system.bash' 
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser
```

My environment is Fedora 37, x86_64.  All software is current.  I tried a few things, like removing the attachment and the date in the mail subject line, but I can't get past that it all works running from command line, and only mailx fails with systemd.  No errors or other messages with journalctl.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: First and most importantly, __read the logs from stderr__. Without them, neither you nor we know exactly what went wrong. You can retrieve them with `journalctl -u yourservicename`

Comment: Second, don't use `bash -c` this way. If your script is executable, just run `ExecStart=/home/myuser/bin/system.bash` (but if it's an executable, also, don't give it a `.bash` extension at all; just set the file permissions to have the +x bit, and make the first line be a shebang -- `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar)

Comment: BTW, you probably want to set this service to have `Type=oneshot` so it isn't sending emails over and over and over, several times a second until systemd marks the unit as broken and stops trying to run it at all anymore.

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  As mentioned in my question, `journalctl` revealed nothing.  For `bash -c` I tried it both ways.  For the timer I have it set for once per day.  It does not run over and over.

Comment: Have you looked at `systemctl status yourservice` / `systemctl show yourservice`?

Comment: And what does `systemd-analyze verify yourservice` have to say?

Comment: Also, the documentation for mailx gives you a lot of advice about how to run it reliably from scripts. Have you read and followed that section of the man page? `User=myuser` doesn't set up `myuser`'s environment variables, and it's very bad form to write scripts that _depend on_ per-user setup; instead, build the script to be self-contained, or to explicitly refer to a configuration file (as by setting a `MAILRC` variable, either inside the script or with an `Environment=` line in the service file)